# Sonata Admin - convert seconds to milliseconds

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, milliseconds

I am generating my view with fields to display in sonata admin panel. I have a float field in my db that is representing seconds that needs to be converted in milliseconds (multiplied by 1000 and rounded to 0 decimals) for display.

Can anybody help out.

Code:

```
  protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{

    $ms = $getMs->getResponseTime(); --- this works
    $milliseconds = round($ms / 1000, 2);


    $showMapper
        ->tab('Info')
        ->add('id')
        ->add('fieldOne')
        ->add('fildTwo')
        ->add('seconds', 'decimal', array(
            'pattern' => $milliseconds
        ))
        ->end()
        ->end()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To round a number UP to the nearest integer, look at [the ceil function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_ceil.asp).
To round a number DOWN to the nearest integer, look at [the floor function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_floor.asp).

```
/* Seconds */
$s = $getMs->getResponseTime();

/* Milliseconds */
$ms = $s*1000;

/* Rounded milliseconds */
$milliseconds = floor($ms);
```